ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error
I've recently been learning some basic socket programming but I keep getting this error when I run my client after the server file.

[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

These were both created with Python IDLE 3.6.
Server:
import socket
import time
my_socket= socket.socket() #1
my_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',54321))
my_socket.listen()

print("Server is listening on port 54321...")
new_socket,addr = my_socket.accept()
print('Connected to: ' + str(addr))

new_socket.sendall(b'Hello from server\n')
time.sleep(0.1) #time lag between two data
new_socket.sendall(b'on server\n')
new_socket.close()
my_socket.close()

Client:
import socket

my_socket=socket.socket()
address= '127.0.0.1'  
port=54321
my_socket.connect((address,port)) 
data=b''
while b'\n' not in data:
    data= data + my_socket.recv(1024)
print(data.decode)
my_socket.close()

This error keeps appearing even though I have closed both shells and restarted the whole program. I tried changing the port numbers, too.

Could be firewall blocking your connection between client& server

@rasjani: firewall blocking connections on localhost?

Works for me. Since you use 127.0.0.1 - Do these programs get executed on the same system and - if virtual environments are involved - in the same virtual environment?

I did some tests on the standard machine and saw that the server is working normally. It seems that when you make the first connection, the server closes because your code does not contain a loop and is only sequential.
The correct approach would be:
print("Server is listening on port 54321...")
while True:
    new_socket, addr = my_socket.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + str(addr))

    new_socket.sendall(b'Hello from server\n')
    time.sleep(0.1) # time lag between two data
    new_socket.sendall(b'on server\n')
    new_socket.close()

This way, your server won't terminate and will accept as many requests as needed.
It's also important to note, as mentioned in your question, to ensure that both the client and the server are running on the same machine since you are using a local network (127.0.0.1).

hi, thank you for your suggestion! I tried it out but the same error is still occurring, i tried turning off my firewall too
